# i need to search for passager inside of nested list using linq in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq

```
preresponse.Where(x =>
    x.hotels.Any(h => h.Travellers.Any(t => t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                         || t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                         || t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                         || t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText))
    || x.cars.Any(c => c.Travellers.Any(t => t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                          || t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                          || t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                          || t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText))
    || x.tours.Any(s => s.Travellers.Any(t => t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                           || t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                           || t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                           || t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText))
    || x.flights.Any(f => f.Travellers.Any(t => t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                             || t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                             || t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)
                                             || t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText))
    ))))).ToList();
```

I am using above query, it works fine for hotel, car and flight , but not working on tours traveler 
can anyone find what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something wrong with the parentheses. I have formatted the code, maybe you meant it to be like this:

```
preresponse.Where(x => 
    x.hotels.Any(h => 
        h.Travellers.Any(t => 
            t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)))
        || 
    x.cars.Any(c => 
        c.Travellers.Any(t => 
            t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)))
        || 
    x.tours.Any(s => 
        s.Travellers.Any(t => 
            t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)))
        || 
    x.flights.Any(f => 
        f.Travellers.Any(t => 
            t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText) || 
            t.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(request.SearchText)))
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: i'm getting booking of hotel, car flight and tour in preresponse object then applying filter on their name , email ,im getting result in hotel car and flight case but when i search traveller in tour , im getting null